# How to set an icon in an edit control?

Tags: mfc, cedit

I tried the following snippet but it doesn't show up:

```
HICON hIcon = LoadIcon(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));
myeditcontrol.SetIcon(hIcon, FALSE);
```

Answer (score 1):

The icon associated with a window shows up in the taskbar button, the caption bar, and the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> dialog. It is only meaningful for a top-level window.

Calling [CWnd::SetIcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cb3b7b5.aspx) for a non top-level window (like a [CEdit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7yhsd2b.aspx) control) has no effect. If you want to display graphics in an Edit control, you'll have to go with something more capable, like a [Rich Edit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787605.aspx) control (see [CRichEditCtrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76a787xf.aspx) for an MFC wrapper).